# Separate the elements I extracted from a web page by columns and print them in csv with python

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am starting to learn Python, I have this code which works fine for web scraping, I already have the info that I want and I am sending that data to a CSV but it prints all the text in just one cell.

Can you help me to fix it so I can print each element in a different column?

This is my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
with open('output_file_name', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer3 = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=';')

file4 = open('hola4.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer4 = csv.writer(file4)


class Table:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def get_column_info(self):
        column_info = []
        columns = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/table/thead/tr/th")
        for column in columns:
            column_info.append(str(column.text.replace("%","")))
            writer2.writerow([column_info])
        return column_info


    def get_results(self, index=None):
       columns = self.get_column_info()
       data = {}
       elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'resumen_mensual']/table/tbody[@id = 'body_tmes' ]/tr[contains(@class, 'ini')]{}"
                                                    .format("[{}]".format(index) if index else ""))
       for elementos in elements:
           prueba = elementos.text.strip()


       for element in elements:
           current_index = elements.index(element) + 1 if not index else index
           parsed_data = {}
           for column in columns:
               value = element.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'resumen_mensual']/table/tbody[@id = 'body_tmes' ]/tr[contains(@class, 'ini')][{}]"
                                                      "/td[{}]"
                                                      .format(current_index,columns.index(column) + 1)).text
               parsed_data.update({column: str(value)})
           data.update({current_index:  parsed_data})
       return data


    def get_number_of_results(self):
        return len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'resumen_mensual']/table/tbody[@id = 'body_tmes' ]/tr[contains(@class, 'ini')]"))


if "__main__" == __name__:
    table = Table(driver)

    writer4.writerow([table.get_column_info()])
    writer3.writerow([table.get_results()])

    table = Table(driver)

    print(table.get_column_info())
```

I have this as a result if I run it:

`['DÍA', 'T. MEDIA', 'T. MÁX', 'T. MÍN', 'V. MEDIA VIENTO', 'RACHAS MÁX', 'PRESIÓN MEDIA', 'LLUVIA']`

and in csv:

[image: csv result]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `writer2.writerow([column_info])`.

Set delimiters to `\t` (`delimiter='\t'`).

Instead of:

```py
writer4.writerow([table.get_column_info()])
writer3.writerow([table.get_results()])
```

do:

```py
for info in table.get_column_info():
    writer4.writerow(info)
for result in table.get_results():
    writer3.writerow(result)
```

Comment: First of all thanks, is a huge improvement

Now about your corrections whats the name of those commands or characterisitcs you can add to the inside of the paranthesis such like this (delimiter='\t'), what does that even means and how can I get info of all the things that can be modified there?

Now about the code I still have an error, which is this:
    writer3.writerow(result)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int

And the csv instead of having each word by column it appears by row, and besides the word is separated by cells, one letter per cell

Comment: `\t` means tabulator